SSRS - Blank Page at the end of PDF with Hidden Rectangles
I'm having an issue with hidden rectangles causing a blank page at the end of the report. My report can end up being either 1 or 2 pages total based on if the last couple of rectangles are hidden or not.  I've tried everything that the Microsoft says to check. Confirmed that this is true --> Report body width <= Report page width - (Left margin + Right margin). What my report had is 7.5 <= 8.5 - (.5 + .5).  My page units are inches and orientation is Portrait. There is no space between last rectangle and the footer. There are no page breaks happening in any of the rectangles that could be causing this. ConsumeContainerWhitespace is set to true.
The rectangles that are causing this issue have either tablixs and/or textboxes in them. I have one visibility check to hide the rectangle if there are no rows coming back for the dataset for the tablix that is inside this rectangle. For the other rectangle, it will hide based on a certain value that comes back from a specific dataset in the report. With both of those last 2 rectangles hidden, there is still 15% - 20% blank space on the page. If I remove those rectangles, the last blank page at the end disappears.
I'm using the latest Report Builder application. I'm at a loss as to what can be causing this blank page.

could you share your report design screen ?
